# leaflet disable zoom to marker and how to keep popups always active

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hello I have an application that plots a persons location and his friends locations on a leaflet map. I use two seperate functions for this because there are multiple friends etc.

When it plots the user logged in it will zoom to his location, and then when it plots the friend it will zoom to his location. I need it so that the popups for all markers are always active, and it doesn't zoom to either of the markers.

```
  var markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
  function addMarkerGroup(lat_ret,lon_ret,map,user){
    map.removeLayer(markers);
    markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    var marker = L.marker([lat_ret, lon_ret]).addTo(map).bindPopup("User:" + user).openPopup();
    markers.addLayer(marker);
    map.addLayer(markers);
  }

  var friend_markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
  function addFriendMarkerGroup(lat_ret,lon_ret,map,user){
    map.removeLayer(friend_markers);
    friend_markers = new L.FeatureGroup();
    var friend_marker = L.marker([lat_ret, lon_ret]).addTo(map).bindPopup("User:" + user).openPopup();
    friend_markers.addLayer(friend_marker);
    map.addLayer(friend_markers);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the map zooms when opening a popup? Too my knowledge the map only pans so that the popup is visible. I also see nothing in your code that implements zoom so i think you're mistaken. If you want to disable panning to a popup that's just opened you can disable the `autoPan` option:

```
new L.Marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('Foo', {
    autoPan: false
}).addTo(map).openPopup();
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#popup-autopan

Keeping two popups open at the same time isn't possible with overwriting your `L.Map`'s `openPopup` function with your own in where you comment/leave out the line where the currently opened popup is closed:

```
L.Map.include({
    openPopup: function (popup, latlng, options) { // (Popup) or (String || HTMLElement, LatLng[, Object])

        // Commented out, previous popup(s) will remain open 
        // this.closePopup();

        if (!(popup instanceof L.Popup)) {
            var content = popup;

            popup = new L.Popup(options)
                .setLatLng(latlng)
                .setContent(content);
        }
        popup._isOpen = true;

        this._popup = popup;
        return this.addLayer(popup);
    }
});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/0LPYmhJ3ew8wSBXBM6XC?p=preview

In Leaflet 1.0 (which is currently beta) there's a new popup option called `autoClose` which will solve this:

```
new L.Marker([0, 0]).bindPopup('Foo', {
    autoClose: false
}).addTo(map).openPopup();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to give autoPan: false and autoClose: false in bindPopup()

```
var testMarkerOne = L.circle([21.7679, 78.8718], 80500, {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).bindPopup('Marker 1', { autoPan: false, autoClose: false });
    var testMarkerTwo = L.circle([13.0448, 77.6221], 80500, {
                    color: 'red',
                    fillColor: '#f03',
                    fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).bindPopup('Marker 2', { autoPan: false, autoClose: false } );

var testMarkerThree = L.circle([15.2993, 74.1240], 80500, {
                color: 'red',
                fillColor: '#f03',
                fillOpacity: 0.5
}).bindPopup('Marker 3', { autoPan: false, autoClose: false });
var circleGroup = L.featureGroup([testMarkerOne,testMarkerTwo, testMarkerThree]).addTo(mymap);
circleGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  layer.openPopup();
});
```

You have to give autoPan: false and autoClose: false in bindPopup()